# Unread messages counter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, private-pub

I am creating a simple chatting app on rails 4. The controllers, models and views are created but the functionality is still incomplete. I have 2 tables in my database, conversations and messages. The conversation table holds two fields, sender id and receiver id. And the messages table holds 3 fields, body, user id and read(defaults to 0 meaning not read).

Models:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, :class_name => "User"
    belongs_to :reciever, :foreign_key => :reciever_id, :class_name => "User"

    has_many :messages, :dependent => :destroy

    validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :reciever_id

    scope :involving, lambda { |user_id|
        where("sender_id = ? OR reciever_id = ?", user_id, user_id)
    }

    scope :between, lambda { |sender_id, reciever_id|
        where("(sender_id = ? AND reciever_id = ?) OR (sender_id = ? AND reciever_id = ?)", sender_id, reciever_id, reciever_id, sender_id)
    }

    def other_interlocutor(user_id)
        if sender.id == user_id
            return reciever.id
        else
            return sender.id
        end
    end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :conversation_id, :user_id, :body

end
```

What I am trying to do is to create a real-time functionality of receiving unread messages count whenever someone receives a new message. I am using private pub to create the chat between users.

I have a user model which contains this function:

```
def unread_messages_count
    unread_messages = 0
    # puts "Putting self conversations ! #{self.conversations.first}"
    conversations = Conversation.involving(self.id)
    conversations.each do |conversation|
        unread_messages += conversation.messages.where(:read => 0, :user_id => conversation.other_interlocutor(self.id)).count
    end
    return unread_messages = unread_messages == 0 ? nil : unread_messages
end
```

I have one page where all user's conversations are listed and one a conversation is clicked all the messages related to that conversation are listed too. On the same page I have subscribed every `conversation_messages_path` to create separate channels for every conversation. Whenever a message is sent a `create.js.erb` file is rendered where I publish to those subscribed channels:

```
<% publish_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation.id) do %>
    $("#conversations_link").text("<%= current_user.unread_messages_count %> Conversations");
    $("#messages").append("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'message', :locals => { :message => @message })%>");
<% end %>
```

The `$("#conversation_link")` is where I want to show the unread messages count.

Currently, the unread messages count is returning back the wrong count and the navbar is only updated when the `conversation.sender_id` messages the receiver.

My unread message counter is not returning the correct number of unread messages. I don't know how to fix it. What's wrong in my code?
Thanks.

Comment: "What is wrong in my code and what should I do to make this thing work?" As a problem statement, this statement is incredibly vague and non-descriptive. Rather than dumping great big chunks of code, how about trying to isolate the problem to something that can realistically be addressed on SO?

Comment: @MarsAtomic that all code is necessary for one to understand whats going on in my app.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that your domain modeling is really off.

The whole idea of a conversation is that the parties involved take turns being the the sender and recipient. What your have modeled is a *monologue*.

> A monologue is a speech delivered by one person, or a long one-sided
>   conversation that makes you want to pull your hair out from boredom.
>   The Greek root word monologos translates to “speaking alone,” and
>   that's a monologue: one person doing all the talking.

The domain model you end up with here should look something like this:

[image: database diagram]

Its the message that is actually linked to two users (or more): the `sender` and the `recipient`. For the sake of simplicity i'm sticking to 1:1 messaging here (vs group chats where a message may belong to many recipients).

```
class Message
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  has_many :sent_messages, 
           class_name: 'Message', 
           foreign_key: 'sender_id' 
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
end
```

Note that we need to tells Rails the class and the foreign key when it cannot be derived from the association name.

Instead of having a boolean `read` field you might want to consider using a [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to denote the status of the message.

Enums are basically an integer column which maps to a list of symbols.

```
class Message
  enum :status, [:unread, :read] 
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

Enums give you scopes like:

```
Message.unread
Message.read
```

And conditionals such as:

```
message.unread?
message.read?
```

And it makes it very straight forward if you want to add more states such as `:archieved` or `:trashed`.

Armed with this you don't need your `unread_messages_count` monstrosity. Which will eat tons of memory since you are pulling records out of the database just to count the associated records.

```
current_user.messages.unread.size
```

Also we should define the relation between User and Conversation correctly:

```
class Conversation
  has_many :messages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Users
  # ..
  has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations
end
```

This [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relation would store users and converstations in the `users_conversations` join table. You can use the following generator to create the join table migration:

```
rails generate migration users_conversations
```

## Added:

Using `session[:user_id]` in your views is a really bad code smell. You are tightly coupling your authentication logic all over your application.

Instead create a helper:

```
class SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def user_signed_in?
     !current_user.nil?
  end 
end
```

Other parts of the application should not know that you store the current user in `session[:user_id]` just that there is a `current_user`.

Comment: I hope I don't come off as too abrasive here - my aim is not to criticize your abilities but rather show you that your issues are due to some fundamental flaws in the design. The first time I built a messaging system it was epically crap...

Comment: I need to get conversations of one user in which he is either the recipient or sender. How would I do that with this model?

Comment: Just do `user.conversations`

Comment: But you should probably think of it more in terms of "where the user has sent or received messages" since both users are senders and recievers in a conversation.

Comment: So I will get all coversations in which he is sender aswell as recipient?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And to insert records in the joint table i have to do `user.conversations.create!` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81705/discussion-between-maxcal-and-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui).